# Set position to SKSpriteNode after forcefully stop it (i.e. set velocity 0)

Tags: ios, position, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I am getting strange behaviour in my game. I have one `SKSpriteNode`. After give `force` to my `SKSpriteNode`, due to effect of `force` my `SKSpriteNode` starts travelling (i.e `mySpriteNode.physicsBody.isResting == NO`).

**SCENARIO :**

When ball stop it's simulation(i.e `mySpriteNode.physicsBody.isResting == YES`) and i give any `position` to mySpriteNode. this works perfectly.

BUT,

When mySpriteNode is travelling (i.e `mySpriteNode..physicsBody.isResting == NO`) and i give `velocity` **0** to mySpriteNode and it stops(i.e `mySpriteNode..physicsBody.isResting == YES`). But when i give any `position` to it, It doesn't make any effect.

mySpriteNode's `position` is remaining its place where i give 0 velocity.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "giving position" and how are you giving position?

Comment: I do change my position after my game logic. I give position by below stuff ::     myNode.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width - ballOffset, self.size.height/2);

Answer (score -1):

It is Working perfectly for me when I re-position the sprite in the action block completion.

```
SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];

sprite.xScale = 0.5;
sprite.yScale = 0.5;
sprite.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2.0, self.size.height/2.0);
sprite.physicsBody = [ SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:sprite.size];

SKAction *act1 = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    [sprite.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 100)];
}];

SKAction *act2 = [SKAction waitForDuration:2];
SKAction *act3 = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    [sprite.physicsBody setVelocity:CGVectorMake(0, 0)];
}];
SKAction *seq = [SKAction sequence:@[act1,act2,act3]];
[sprite runAction:seq completion:^{
    sprite.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2.0, self.size.height/2.0);
}];


  self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);
```

Try repositioning in completion block of an action.

Comment: Is it working ? why down vote is it wrong to re-position sprite in completion ?

Comment: I do not do any animation by SKAction. I do apply force on my SpriteNode's physics body. And i  stop that SpriteNode after some logic &  wants to give any position to that node.

Comment: Try this and let me know if it works `SKAction *moveSpriteToOriginalPosition = [SKAction moveTo:yourPosition duration:1];
    [sprite runAction:moveSpriteToOriginalPosition];`

Comment: Can you tell me why .position not worked in my case?

Comment: SKActions take some time to execute so if you put a line of code like `mySprite.position = somePoint` immediatly after a SKAction then this line get executed even before the previous SKAction action. So as a result your sprite will not be repositioned as you would expect. In order to solve this you may wrap your repositioning code inside SKAction thats why the above code works.